# Facebook OAuthException error in app. *Easy fix*

Tags: php, facebook

One of my facebook applications is now giving this error after user accepts permissions:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#322) Invalid photo tag subject
>   thrown in /home/me/public_html/mysite/facebook.php on line 522

The app still works fine, but gives that error instead of redirecting to the proper page after user allows permissions.

Thi is line 521 - 529 of facebook.php:

```
if (is_array($result) && isset($result['error'])) {
  $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
  if ($e->getType() === 'OAuthException') {
    $this->setSession(null);
  }
  throw $e;
}
return $result;
```

Can someone help me fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code, it's throwing and Exception that you are not catching. Just wrap the code in a try/catch block and handle it.